# Refresh in browser when uploading mvc file c #

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have an AJAX file upload by call to MVC C# driver, but the browser refreshes and reloads the page.

But if I comment the line that saves the file in the driver does not happen that is only when the file is saved on the server. `File.SaveAs (fname);`

MVC controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadDocument()
{
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            FileUpdateDto fileModal = new FileUpdateDto();

            HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
                string fname;
                DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Document/" + UserId).ToString());
                if (!directory.Exists)
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Document/" + UserId).ToString());
                }
                if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                {
                    string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                    fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    fname = file.FileName;
                }
                var guidnew = Guid.NewGuid();
                fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Document/" + UserId), guidnew + "." + fname.Split('.')[1].ToString());
                fileModal.FileName = fname;
                fileModal.Path = directory.ToString();
                fileModal.DateFileUpload = DateTime.Now;
               file.SaveAs(fname);  //  If I comment this line without refreshing the browser but does not save the file
            }

            return Json(fileModal);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("Error occurred. Error details: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Json("No files selected.");
    }
}
```

Call Ajax in JavaScript:

```js
UploadDocument: function () {
    if (window.FormData !== undefined) {

        var fileUpload = $("#AdviserFileUpload").get(0);
        var files = fileUpload.files;

        var fileData = new FormData();

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
        }
        //fileData.append('username', 'Manas');  

        $.ajax({
            url: site.baseUrl + '/Api/Upload/Document',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: fileData,
            success: function (result) {
                __this._AdviserDocumentFile = result;
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.statusText);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("FormData is not supported.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you cancel the default submit button behaviour when attaching the ajax handler?

Comment: show how UploadDocument is being called. very likely that's where the problem is

Comment: The call of the uploaddocument method is made using the friendly url created in the 

context.MapRoute(
                name: "api_upload_Document",
                url: "Api/Upload/Document",
                defaults: new { controller = "Upload", action = "UploadDocument", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Im using dropzone.js with MVC and its refreshing because of that SaveAs line, commenting it out prevents refresh. It is so weird.

Answer (score 7):

I believe I found the solution. The cause is that Visual Studio's "Enable Reload on Save" property is True.

Go to **Tools - Options - Web - Browser Reload on Save - Enable Reload on Save** and make it false.

Im working with VS2015 and this worked for me, hope it works for you too.

[Source](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BrowserReloadonSave)

Comment: You are amazing

Comment: WOW, I spent an entire day trying so many different things. I thought it was jQuery, then thought it was the form submitting etc...God damn it!!

Comment: I still need the reload on save so when I change JS or CSHTML files, it reloads. I removed image extensions such as png, gif etc. from File extensions