# Ajax call refreshes the client page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas to take screenshot of a div and then upload it to the server. After the image is saved on the server, the page on client refreshes. And that is something I don't want. This is the code, that saves the picture:

```
public void SaveImage(string imageString, int id)
    {
        string s = imageString.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
        byte[] imageB = Convert.FromBase64String(s);

        var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/screens/" + id));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageB))
        {
            using (var image = Image.FromStream(ms))
            {
                image.Save(filePath + "/screen.png", ImageFormat.Png);                          
            }
        }                           
    }
```

This is the Javascript code

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#screen")).then(function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");                      
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SaveImage")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { imageString: data, id: @ViewBag.id },
                    dataType: 'json'                        
                });
            });
```

I have tried some advices I found online like preventDefault() in jQuery. But that's about it. I feel like all the other issues and solutions does not affect me.

EDIT: Simple HTML that refreshes the page too

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            html2canvas(document.querySelector("#screen")).then(function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SaveImage")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { imageString: data, id: 2 },
                    dataType: 'json',
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="screen">Some text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT 1: The whole controller with SaveImage method

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using BcVnc.Models;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace BcVnc.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, User")]    
    public class ConnectionController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext(); 

        // GET: Connection
        public ActionResult Index(int id, bool viewOnly)
        {
            int access = checkUserAccess(id, viewOnly);
            if(access != 0)
            {
                ViewBag.id = id;                
                if (access == 1 & viewOnly == true)
                    ViewBag.viewOnly = true.ToString().ToLower();
                else if(access == 1 && viewOnly == false)
                    ViewBag.viewOnly = false.ToString().ToLower();
                else
                    ViewBag.viewOnly = true.ToString().ToLower();
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }

        private int checkUserAccess(int id, bool viewOnly)
        {
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();            
            var userDevice = db.UserDevices.Where(ud => ud.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault(ud => ud.DeviceId == id);
            var device = db.Devices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == id);
            ViewBag.name = device.Name;

            if (userDevice == null)
                return 0;
            else
            {
                if (userDevice.ViewOnly == false)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return -1;
            }
        }

        public void SaveImage(string imageString, int id)
        {
            string s = imageString.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
            byte[] imageB = Convert.FromBase64String(s);

            var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/screens/" + id));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageB))
            {
                using (var image = Image.FromStream(ms))
                {
                    image.Save(filePath + "/screen.png", ImageFormat.Png);                          
                }
            }                           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the complete action method of "SaveImage". It might be relevant to know, which version of Asp.net (core) you are using.

Comment: I have edited my post. I hope I understand your request. The only thing that was missing was the method name and parameters really.

Comment: We need the complete code, what does the relevant HTML look like?  Ajax calls don't refresh the page, so most likely whatever is triggering `html2canvas` is causing it (probably a submit button in a form).

Comment: I was asking for the whole method, because I was expecting to see some sort of `return View(viewmodel-foo);` call. Since you are using void, instead of some sort of ContentResult type (why?), we need to see your complete html form and javacript code to see if you are submitting to a form or anything else is amiss.

Comment: Even when I make really simple HTML page. Just the basic HTML, with one div with some text in it. Calling the javascript you can see in my original post in $(document).ready function makes the page refresh all over again (and again and again and again ...). No forms, no buttons. I'll edit my question with this simple code.

Comment: I've just rebuilt it in a simple demo. My page does not refresh and the `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` does not change. I can't see any reason why it should though. Please add the whole controller, in which this SaveImage method resides. You are not showing us everything that is relevant

Comment: Another edit with the whole controller.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how come I was not able to find this before, but the whole problem was in Visual Studio settings. The refresh probably would not happen outside the localhost: [Refresh in browser when uploading mvc file c #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829709/refresh-in-browser-when-uploading-mvc-file-c/44128269#44128269)
After changing that in settings, no refresh anymore.