# How can I disable refreshing page ajax call?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using image upload in my project. When I click the upload button and select a file. I am showing images in ajax call with html code, but after then my page is refreshing and the outcome is that all form data blank.

I have also tried using `e.preventDefault` but it has not solved the issue.

My ajax call getting images and splitting.

'.clsDosyalar' is my textbox and I am writing images name here.

**JavaScript**

```
   <script>
              $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#files").on("change", function (e) {
                        var formData = new FormData();
                        var totalFiles = document.getElementById("files").files.length;
                        for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
                            var file = document.getElementById("files").files[i];
                            alert(file.name);
                            formData.append("files", file);
                        }

             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/haber/upload',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.Durum == "1") {
                    if (response.Dosyalar != "") {
                        var res = response.Dosyalar.split(",");

                        if ($('.clsDosyalar').val() == "") {
                            $('.clsDosyalar').val(response.Dosyalar);
                        }

                        else {
                            $('.clsDosyalar').val($('.clsDosyalar').val() + "," + response.Dosyalar);
                        }

                        for (var dlist = 0; dlist < res.length; dlist++) {

                            $("<span class=\"pip\" id=\"pip" + res[dlist] + "\">" +
                              "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + "../../Uploads/" + res[dlist] + "\" title=\"" + res[dlist] + "\"/>" +
                              "<br/><span class=\"remove\" id=\"" + res[dlist] + "\">Fotoğrafı Sil</span><span class=\"gorunurfoto\" id=\"" + res[dlist] + "\">Görünür Fotoğraf</span>" + res[dlist].filename +
                              "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
                        }

                    }

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("Hata");
                }
            });
        });
    });

        </script>
```

**HTML**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Yeni", "Haberler", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HaberImage, "", new { @class = "clsDosyalar form-control" })
    </div>
<input type="file" id="files" name="postedFiles" multiple />
 <input type="submit" value="Ekle" class="btn btn-success" id="btnEkle" />
}
```

**Controller**

I am sending selected images names JsonResult.

```
 [Route("haber/upload")]
    public JsonResult Upload()
    {
        int Durum = 0;
        string strFileNames = "";
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[i];

                var fileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);

                strFileNames += fileName + ",";
            }

            Durum = 1;

        }

        catch
        {
            Durum = 0;
        }

        if (strFileNames != "")
        {
            strFileNames = strFileNames.Substring(0, strFileNames.Length - 1);
        }



        return Json(new { Durum = Durum, Dosyalar = strFileNames });
    }
```

**My ActionResults;**

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("panel/haberekle")]
        public ActionResult Yeni()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("panel/haberekle")]
        public ActionResult Yeni(Haberler haberModel)
        {

            Haberler haber = new Haberler();


            haber.HaberImage = haberModel.HaberImage;
            haber.Baslik = haberModel.Baslik;
            haber.Icerik = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(haberModel.Icerik);
            haber.Tarih = haberModel.Tarih;
            haber.BitisTarihi = haberModel.BitisTarihi;
            haber.AktifMi = haberModel.AktifMi;
            haber.SilindiMi = haberModel.SilindiMi;
            haber.GorunecekImage = haberModel.GorunecekImage;

            using (dbContext = DbContext())
            {
                dbContext.Haberler.Add(haber);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Listele", "Haberler");
        }
```

**Solution link ;**

[Refresh in browser when uploading mvc file c #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829709/refresh-in-browser-when-uploading-mvc-file-c)

Comment: Show your button click event handler please

Comment: @RenanAraújo I don't have click event handler. I have textbox and writing images name here when user selecting.

 My button type is must file bcoz I am choosing images.

Comment: @RenanAraújo I already have submit button.

Comment: I can't see the problem, check this fiddle, it's not posting on file select. https://jsfiddle.net/n1gd9ofy/6/

Comment: changing the selected file in a "file" input wouldn't cause an automatic postback, so the code above is not the cause of your problem. It submits the data once, it doesn't cause any other requests to the server. You mention a submit button, are you clicking that at the same time? It's not clear. Either way we can't solve your problem easily because we haven't got the right code to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @RenanAraújo I know. I am selecting files with my '#files' button and getting images name to textbox. My problem is starting this time. When I select files, my form refreshing. I am not clicking same time. I am choosing images and fill other textbox after then click submit button for saving database.

Comment: @ADyson Yes I have submit button but not clicking same time. I am choosing images, getting images names to textbox and after then fill other textboxes and click submit button.

Comment: is there some other event attached to your file input then? The browser developer tools should be able to tell you what events are attached to it. Like I said, the code above is not causing the issue, as Renan's JSFiddle proves. So we can't really help you except by making debugging suggestions.

Comment: BTW, in your code above you have got `success: function (response) {
                    ...

                    }` in your ajax call. The `...` implies you have not included some code in your example above. What exactly did you miss out from here? Perhaps it's something significant, please show us

Comment: @Developer007 I created another fiddle and I still can't see the problem https://jsfiddle.net/n1gd9ofy/10/

Comment: I edited my codes. Can you look again @RenanAraújo

Comment: @ADyson Can you look again to codes ?

Comment: Unless the button is being clicked, I still can't see anything which would cause the page to submit the form or otherwise refresh itself. When you say "my form refreshes itself", do you mean it calls the Yeni "HttpPost" Yeni "HttpGet" action, or something else? A refresh and a postback could have different causes.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, when I choose images, my HttpGet Yeni calling again.

Comment: Ok so it's a page refresh, not a form submission. But still, there is nothing in your code above which would do that. Renan's last JSFiddle proved it. We can't reproduce your problem at all, sorry. You'll maybe have to do some trial and error - strip out parts of your code (but leaving the page still able to do the file upload) until it stops happening, and hopefully that will reveal the source of the issue.

Comment: @ADyson I necessary to use image upload.  :( Thanks for helping

Comment: I didn't say you had to remove the image upload. Read my comment again.

Comment: @ADyson Ah I saw his comment. I will try. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ADyson Hello again, I found my solution now :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829709/refresh-in-browser-when-uploading-mvc-file-c

Here is link. It is Visual Studio problem.

Comment: @RenanAraújo I am okey now. I edited my post. Thanx for helping guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually submit your form by making submit button to `type="button"`

Put a submit action on its click function

```
$('#myButton').on('click',function(){ 
   $(this).closest('form').submit(); 
});
```